# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 in pure swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have divided project into few frameworks. It compiles fine when debuging in both simulator and on the iPhone. But when I try to archive or profile it gives me:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "Observation.Observation.__allocating_init (observer : Swift.AnyObject, listener : (Any) -> ()) -> Observation.Observation", referenced from:
  WebService.WebServiceRequestOperation.init (dependencies : [__ObjC.Operation]?, progressObservation : (observer : Swift.AnyObject, listener : (Any) -> ())?, finishBlock : (WebService.WebServiceRequestOperation) -> ()?) -> WebService.WebServiceRequestOperation in WebServiceRequestOperation.o
  WebService.WebServiceBackgroundDownloadOperation.init (urlString : Swift.String, dependencies : [__ObjC.Operation]?, progressObservation : (observer : Swift.AnyObject, listener : (Any) -> ())?, finishBlock : (WebService.WebServiceBackgroundDownloadOperation) -> ()?) -> WebService.WebServiceBackgroundDownloadOperation in WebServiceBackgroundDownloadOperation.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tried everything I have found on the internet about similar bugs, but nothing works. I think the problem is when Xcode used Release instead of Debug mode. I tried changing some options in Build Settings to be the same in Release as in Debug, but nothing worked. This project contains only swift source files - no compiled frameworks.

Comment: Did you embed the framework?

Comment: Yes, all frameworks are embedded in main target

Comment: Then, one of the framework (may be `WebService`) is not built for armv7 architecture. That might be one of the reasons for this

Comment: And you build the frameworks for arm7?

Comment: @shallowThought, When you make a framework, you include every iOS architecture in script file. You can check this link for more details (https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c). I had experience building one.

Comment: I know. Double check. In terminal: `file /path/to/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework`

Comment: All frameworks have the same Valid Architectures selected - default ones. I even created new project, created new frameworks from the beginning and added source files again to test this with default settings.

Comment: I can only check few of these in terminal, as other are not compiling because of these errors. The ones I can test gives:
Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [arm_v7: Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm_v7] [arm64: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64]
Observation.framework/Observation (for architecture armv7): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library arm_v7
Observation.framework/Observation (for architecture arm64): Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64